# Bind9 (on local DNS) taking a long time to use zones from public DNS servers

Tags: ubuntu, domain-name-system, bind, replication

My local DNS servers (ubuntu, bind9) are supposed to simply forward from my public name servers. However, if I make changes to public IP addresses, the information will replicate to Google, ATT, etc. within a few minutes, but takes as long as a day to for my local DNS. My local DNS servers are set to forward directly to my external name servers. Any reason why this would happen?

I almost feel like if I were to flush the cache of the local DNS servers, it would fix the issue, but I've done this before and it has broken things (not really in the mood for that, lol).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My local DNS servers (ubuntu, bind9) are supposed to simply forward
>   from my public name servers.

Are you sure that in your /etc/bind/named.conf.options you have correctly set
bind to forward first and defined forwarders?

Or are have you configured BIND to be a slave to your public name servers? 
Two totally different things that BIND can do.
if the latter

In your /etc/bind/{zone} change the refresh time.
More information on the conf file and how to do so [here](http://www.zytrax.com/books/dns/ch8/soa.html)